# Weird Pattern in the Power Spectrum diagram (i.e. the frequency domain of the signal)

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum, noise

I am quite a newbie to signal processing. I convert the time-domain signal to the frequency domain with the automated power-spectrum generator in the matlab app. The frequency domain has this reoccurring trough. I am really not sure what type of noises this is indicating. THe signal is from a 3-axis accelerometer.
Any little help or suggestion is truly appreciated. Please let me know if I posted in the wrong forum.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons:

1. A low pass filter is active. The ripple looks like a typical filter stopband ripple.
2. It is due to the way the spectrum is calculated. Check the settings and play around with them. Try some tapered window function (e.g. Hann or Hamming) and some overlap, e.g. 50%.

Comment: I just found out that the signal in the picture was passed through a hampel filter. Would you reckon that this ripple thingy was caused by spectral leakage? Cause hampel filter was like taking median from each square window right?

Comment: Yes, a Hampel filter is a kind of low pass, essentially. It does not have a transfer function the same way as, say, a Butterworth filter has, because it is non-linear and therefore signal dependent. But the ripples you see could well be caused by it.